# PyroCMS Dynamic info menu

Tags: php, codeigniter, pyrocms

In **PyroCMS** you can create a submenu for your custom module using the

```
$info['sections'][...]
```

array. Rather than returning the same menu, based on the current section the user is in I want to offer a seperate menu.

Something like this;

```
if($section =='my_order')
{
   return $info = array(...);
}
else
{
   return $info = array(...);
}
```

But Im not sure how to check which section the user is in in the details.php file

any suggestions ideas greatly appreciated.

*Im using PyroCMS 2.2*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the section is in the URL, that's an easy way.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html

```
if($this->uri->segment(2) == 'my_order'){
    ...
```